# Mobicents Diameter

Tags: java, jboss, voip

I want to use the Mobicents Diameter implementation to build my Application , but I do not need the mobicent or the JBoss , is it possible to use the Mobicents Diameter for (Rf, sh, ...)interfaces alone without installing the jboss and Mobicents server ?

Answer (score 1):

Missed this. Stack has all APPs coded. SLEE provides RAs per application, the RAs use stack implementation of APP sessions - Sh, CCA, Ro,Rf... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source repo for Mobicents jDiameter:

https://code.google.com/p/jdiameter/

Github mirror:

https://github.com/Mobicents/jdiameter

Answer (score 0):

You can check the standalone examples at https://github.com/Mobicents/jdiameter/tree/master/examples which do not need JBoss at all